# WPF DataGrid columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

```
DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();

col.Header = "Text1";
col.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Text1");  
grd.Columns.Add(col);
```

I want to get the Binding propertyname for each column

```
foreach (DataGridTextColumn column in grd.Columns)
  {

  }
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridTextColumn column in grd.Columns)
{
    Binding binding = column.Binding as Binding;
    string propertyName = null;
    if (binding != null)
        propertyName = binding.Path.Path;
}
```

Comment: There is no property column.Binding.Path.Path;

I need to get the property name to which the column is bound.
In my case I want to get Text1(Binding)

Comment: Fixed the code, I mistakenly assumed the `Binding` property was of type `Binding`, it was of the base type `BindingBase` instead.